Track dates at which a status changes to a specific value
I have a table my_table like this:
                     id                  |          updated_at           | status 
-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------
 ID1                                     | 2023-12-18 18:37:21.724825+00 | I
 ID1                                     | 2024-01-02 23:08:03.50741+00  | I
 ID1                                     | 2024-01-03 23:07:03.892617+00 | I
 ID1                                     | 2024-01-06 23:09:00.877018+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-01-07 23:08:03.134111+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-01-08 23:06:31.164932+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-03 23:39:39.138697+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-04 23:55:54.582789+00 | F
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-05 23:37:15.70314+00  | F
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-06 23:47:16.814729+00 | F
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-07 23:42:54.349137+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-08 23:35:53.188792+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-03-09 23:30:55.979575+00 | A
 ID1                                     | 2024-04-10 08:30:05.329453+00 | F
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-15 23:52:28.005298+00 | A
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-16 23:53:38.031816+00 | A
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-17 23:57:42.556396+00 | A
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-18 13:33:38.264444+00 | A
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-18 22:48:29.366489+00 | A
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-19 15:00:02.19655+00  | F
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-26 18:37:13.514644+00 | A
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-27 15:19:13.823159+00 | F
 ID2                                     | 2024-03-28 15:31:46.841049+00 | F
 ID2                                     | 2024-04-03 07:43:08.253604+00 | P

I would like to select from it the dates at which the status changes from any value to the value F, i.e I am expecting the following output:
ID1   | 2024-03-04 23:55:54.582789+00
ID1   | 2024-04-10 08:30:05.329453+00
ID2   | 2024-03-19 15:00:02.19655+00
ID2   | 2024-03-27 15:19:13.823159+00

So far, I managed to get the first time such a change occurs for each id, but I can't get subsequent changes. Here is my query:
    SELECT
        id, updated_at
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *
            , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at ASC) AS rank_
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status='F' ) t_sub
    ) T
    WHERE rank_ = 1

How to change it to get not only the first time each id turns to the status F, but also second, third, fourth, etc... changes to F?

Look for rows where the status values is different from lag(status)over(partition by id order by updated_at) window function.

Set up a subquery where you establish whether a row has status='F' and the value of lag(status)over(partition by id order by updated_at) window function is different from it, then only select those: demo
select id,updated_at 
from(select *
           ,status<>lag(status,1,status)over w1 and status='F' as changed_to_f
     from my_table
     window w1 as (partition by id order by updated_at) ) as subquery
where changed_to_f;




id
updated_at




ID1
2024-03-04 23:55:54.582789+00


ID1
2024-04-10 09:30:05.329453+01


ID2
2024-03-19 15:00:02.19655+00


ID2
2024-03-27 15:19:13.823159+00



It's a strict interpretation: this does not catch the rows that are the initial row of a given ID, because there's no prior row it would be changing from. If you do want to also catch those:
select id,updated_at 
from(select *,status is distinct from lag(status)over w1 and status='F' 
              as changed_to_f
             ,status<>lag(status,1,status||'.')over w1 and status='F' 
              as also_changed_to_f
     from my_table
     window w1 as (partition by id order by updated_at) ) as subquery
where changed_to_f
order by 1,2;


thank you very much ! works like a charm. The lag function was what I was missing, it enables to access previous data from the current row according to the documentation, nice one !!
